# make: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm working a class assignment from machine learning course. We are given a hmm.tar file which contains c++ implementation of hidden markov models.

In the read me file the following was given.

> To compile and test the program,
>
> 1) extract the code:
>
> ```
> tar -xf hmm.tar
> ```
>
> 2) compile the programs:
>
> ```
> make all
> ```

at the second step the output from the terminal is `make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop`

I'm using windows10 OS and running cygwin terminal.

Please help me to sort this problem out. Here's the 
[Makefile](http://pastebin.com/1qCTBJg0)

Comment: What was the contents of the tarfile. Does it contain a makefile and does that makefile contain the 'all' target?

Comment: @RobertKock It has a Makefile. I edited the question to add the contents of the Makefile

Comment: Is the Makefile that long? Proxy forbids pastebin here (and in few months, link may get broken).

Comment: try "make -f Makefile" and tell us the output.

Comment: `$ make -f Makefile
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile'.  Stop.` This the output of `make -f Makefile`

Comment: I don't know why its saying "no such file". There is a Makefile in the .tar file.

Comment: I'd suspect that hmm.tar extracts all the files in a directory e.g. `hmm`. Have you done `cd hmm` (or whatever it is called) before launching `make all`?

Comment: I'm in the same directory where the .tar file is. I don't understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the tar file has files inside a subdirectory.  You probably just need to make sure you're in the directory that has the Makefile, and then run make:

```
tar -xf hmm.tar
cd __somewhere_
make all
```

to help you know where the Makefile is, you could use:

```
tar tf hmm.tar | grep -i makefile
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the ouput of the terminal is 
`krish@DESKTOP-5KVRRBS /cygdrive/c
$ tar -xf hmm-1.04.tar.gz

krish@DESKTOP-5KVRRBS /cygdrive/c
$ cd hmm-1.04

krish@DESKTOP-5KVRRBS /cygdrive/c/hmm-1.04
$ make all
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
`

Comment: That looks like a different error to before.  You could maybe try "make clean" first, then "make all".  Other things to know .. I pretty much always extract tar using -v too so that you see which files are extracted "tar xvf hmm.tar".   And you can specify multiple make rules together "make clean all".

Comment: I tried using "make clean" before using make all. Surprisingly it worked. Can you tell me why it worked?

Comment: "make all" is trying to ensure that everything required for the "all" target has been built. From your Makefile, this is "train_hmm test_hmm generate_seq".  Presumably, those files were inside the tar file too. "make clean" is deleting those files so that next time you run "make all" they have to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

Since cygwin returns `make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop`, it seems that `make` is installed correctly.
As such, it has to be two other things:

- Either the make file inside the.tar is missing, or
- there are syntactical errors present in the make file

Comment: The makefile is present inside the .tar file. That leaves us with syntactical errors in the make file